# Navigate your Android with Cardboard

Tags: applications, 5.1-lollipop, virtualization, google-cardboard

Can I view my phone with the screen split-duplicated and turned sideways (for use with Cardboard)? I have a controller for navigation.

I am looking to run regular apps, see my regular homescreen, etc., but with the screen split and rotated sideways (for use with Cardboard).

Comment: Umm, just to let you know that if the apps don't support 3D, it's useless to use Cardboard, since you're going to see flat screen anyway. (In other words: making screen split-duplicated doesn't automagically make it 3D)

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't care about 3D, a fixed image is preferred, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

As per today I have found nothing that solves your problem.
(I also don't see any use for it but that is another question.)